# Wrapping div element size is zero

Tags: css, html

```
I have the following nested elements : 

<div class="simple-score-bar">
<span class="score-heading">heading</span>
<div class="score-wrapper">
    <div class="score-label">
        <span>76</span>
    </div>
    <div class="score-chart">
        <div>
            <svg>
                <g>
                    <rect width="400px" height="30px"></rect>
                    <g>
                        <rect width="100px" height="30px"></rect>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue is that the `score-bar` and `score-wrapper` div heights are 0 , when I inspect them. I wonder why this happens.

CSS:

```
.simple-score-bar {
  font-family :'Open Sans Bold', 'Open Sans';
  .score-heading {
    fill: #3D7CD1;
    font-style: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .score-wrapper {
    .score-chart {
      float: left;
      width: 80%;
      .score-legend {
        font-size: 10px;
        font-style: normal;
        color: #778599;
        line-height: normal;
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        .score-left {
          float: left;
        }
        .score-right {
          float: right;
        }
        .score-text {
          font-weight: 700;
        }
        .score-value {
          font-weight: 400;
        }
      }
    }
    .score-label {
      float:left;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-style: normal;
      margin-right: 3%;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: updated the question with the css styling

Comment: Ah yes. floating contents. Clear the floats at the end.

Comment: so how to handle the positions then ?

Comment: Like I said, clear the floats. I'll write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) on those elements.

When you float elements you take them out of the normal document flow. The parent element that they reside in will treat them as if they take up no space. If all elements within another element are floated it will collapse and behave like it is an empty element visually.

Using a clearfix allows those floated elements to take up space within the parent. This is useful if you're apply a border or background color on a parent element of floated elements.

```css
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}    
.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Floated block level elements will collapse to the size of their content. As a result you may need to clear some floated elements if you want them to appear below the previously floated element.

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 3px;
  }
div:nth-of-type(3) {
  clear: left; /* move third div to the next line */
  }
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that none of the floats in your code are cleared, so the outer divs don't really have any tangible content.

The solution is to have the floats cleared after the end of the divs they appear in.

```css
.simple-score-bar::after, .score-wrapper::after {
   clear:both; content:''; display:block; height:0;
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j944y0v4/), where I include some Javascript to report the height of the score-wrapper.